# Dependency management automation for client and server with node

Tags: node.js, dependency-management

When implementing web apps with node, in package.json dependencies are declared for the application and written in node_modules. Now, having the dependencies on the server, there are dependencies which are needed on the client, and perhaps on the server as well.

What's best practice? Simply implementing a task to copy (and concatenate) the files to the directory which holds the client libraries?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch), [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Comment: Also, [Ender.js](http://ender.no.de/).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestions! I'll work my way through them. Seems like at least one of them will fit my needs.